# Change Laravel app on shared hosting root directory

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

We have an added domain on a shared hosting. This domain is not the main hosting domain, but an added one that points to directory that matches the domain. The app was installed with a one click installer inside a dir like

ourdomain.com and Laravel public directory is accessed like

ourdomain.com/public

I need to use .htaccess to make /public the root of ourdomain.com and at the same time /public, so the project files and folders are protected as well. Can someone help show me how to do this with .htaccess?

Comment: Don't forget to hide everything except `public`. Your `.env` file is not for guests' eyes

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the access to change the settings in anything like CPANEL or similar then you can do it like this via `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ourdomain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ourdomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```